# How can I improve my product facet search database model (EAV)

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb

I have created a facet search for a product catalog like [following screen image](https://isquared.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/ebay.png) and wonder if I designed it correctly.

I found Joel Brown's [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15211) with an ERD that sketches an Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model. I tried to build this model in Sequel Pro and run following query:

```
select     distinct P.* 
from       attribute_product_values APV 
INNER JOIN products P
on         P.ID = APV.product_id
left JOIN  attribute_values AV
on         AV.ID = APV.attribute_value_id
and        AV.value_id = 6
left JOIN  attribute_values AV2
on         AV2.ID = APV.attribute_value_id
and        AV2.value_id = 3
where      AV.ID is not null 
or         AV2.ID is not null
```

The result of above query was as expected but the query looks very odd to me because of the following reasons:

1. If I remove the distinct value I get the same product multiple
   times
2. I have to use a left join instead of an inner join
3. I have to add a 'where not null' statement for each value I am
   searching for

As of above reasons I feel that I have wrongly designed the relationships between the tables.

I was wondering if the below data model can be designed better in order to make the query simpler and faster ?

---

Here is the SQL dump of the tables:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;


# Dump of table attribute_categories
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `attribute_categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attribute_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_attribute_categories_cat` (`category_id`),
  KEY `fk_attribute_categories_att` (`attribute_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_attribute_categories_att` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `attributes` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_attribute_categories_cat` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

LOCK TABLES `attribute_categories` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `attribute_categories` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `attribute_categories` (`id`, `attribute_id`, `category_id`)
VALUES
    (1,1,1),
    (2,2,1);

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `attribute_categories` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;


# Dump of table attribute_product_values
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `attribute_product_values` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attribute_value_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attribute_category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_attribute_product_values_att` (`attribute_value_id`),
  KEY `fk_attribute_product_values_cat` (`attribute_category_id`),
  KEY `fk_attribute_product_values_pro` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_attribute_product_values_att` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_value_id`) REFERENCES `attribute_values` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_attribute_product_values_cat` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_category_id`) REFERENCES `attribute_categories` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_attribute_product_values_pro` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

LOCK TABLES `attribute_product_values` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `attribute_product_values` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `attribute_product_values` (`id`, `attribute_value_id`, `attribute_category_id`, `product_id`)
VALUES
    (1,2,1,1),
    (2,5,2,1),
    (3,3,1,2),
    (4,6,2,2),
    (6,3,1,3),
    (7,6,2,3);

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `attribute_product_values` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;


# Dump of table attribute_values
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `attribute_values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attribute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_attribute` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `fk_value` (`value_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_attribute` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `attributes` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_value` FOREIGN KEY (`value_id`) REFERENCES `values` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

LOCK TABLES `attribute_values` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `attribute_values` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `attribute_values` (`id`, `attribute_id`, `value_id`)
VALUES
    (1,1,1),
    (2,1,2),
    (3,1,3),
    (4,1,4),
    (5,2,5),
    (6,2,6);

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `attribute_values` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;


# Dump of table attributes
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `attributes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

LOCK TABLES `attributes` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `attributes` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `attributes` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,'Television Resolution'),
    (2,'Television Feature');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `attributes` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;


# Dump of table categories
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

LOCK TABLES `categories` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `categories` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,'Television');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `categories` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;


# Dump of table products
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ` name` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

LOCK TABLES `products` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `products` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, ` name`, `price`)
VALUES
    (1,'Sony ',298),
    (2,'Samsung',252),
    (3,'LG',45);

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `products` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;


# Dump of table values
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

LOCK TABLES `values` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `values` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `values` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,'4K Ultra HD'),
    (2,'1080p'),
    (3,'1080i'),
    (4,'760p'),
    (5,'Smart TV'),
    (6,'3D');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `values` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;



/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand the requirement as:

*Return all products having attributes where attribute is of type Television Feature and value is 3D and attribute is of type Television Resolution and value is 1080i*

First create this view:

```
create view v_product_attributes AS
select 
  V.name AS attribute_value,
  A.name AS attribute_name,
  APV.product_id AS product_id
  from
  `values` V -- note: bad practice to use reserved words as table/attribute names
  inner join
  attribute_values AV ON AV.value_id = V.id
  inner join
  attributes A ON A.id = AV.attribute_id
  inner join
  attribute_product_values APV ON APV.attribute_value_id = AV.value_id
```

This query should produce the desired result:

```
SELECT
   P.*
FROM
   products P
inner join
   v_product_attributes A1 ON A1.product_id = P.id AND A1.attribute_name = 'Television Resolution' AND A1.attribute_value = '1080i'
inner join
   v_product_attributes A2 ON A2.product_id = P.id AND A2.attribute_name = 'Television Feature' AND A2.attribute_value = '3D'
```